# Client-side persistence layer for backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm looking for a client-side persistence layer that works with backbone.js.  Something along the lines of [lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) but that plugs in to the backbone model layer.  I've thought about writing my own -- override `Backbone.sync` with a caching layer which looks up things in HTML5 storage and delegates to the original `Backbone.sync` to talk to the server.  I know this problem is really hard to do right and generally, but I can get by with fairly minimal caching logic.

I'd rather not re-invent the wheel if somebody else has already done it.  Know of any solutions?

Comment: Does lawnchair play nicely with backbone?  Sorry I haven't worked with them enough to know if they work at the same level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's an implementation of backbone.sync that uses local storage: https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage

this could be adapted to do local storage and then sync to the server